# Solve by using Lagrange Multiplier Method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

> $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $s > 0$.
>
> $S = \{(x, y, z) | 0 < x < s, 0 < y < s, 0 < z < s, x + y + z = 2s\}$.
>
> $f(x, y, z) = (s - x) (s - y) (s - z)$
>
> Find all the points $(x, y, z) \in S$ that maximaize the value of $f$ by using Lagrange Multiplier Method.

Let $T =\{(x, y, z) | 0 \leq x \leq s, 0 \leq y \leq s, 0 \leq z \leq s, x + y + z = 2s\}$.

$T$ is a compact set and $f$ is continuous.

So, $f$ has a maximum on $T$.

$(\frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s) \in T$ and $f(\frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s) = \frac{s^3}{27} > 0$.

So, the maximum value is larger than $0$.

If $x = s$ or $y = s$ or $z = s$, then $f = 0$.

If $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ or $z = 0$, then $f = 0$.

So, if $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a maximum point on $T$, then  $(x_0, y_0, z_0) \in S$.

So, $f$ has a maximum on $S$.

Let $g(x, y, z) = x + y + z - 2s$.

$g = 0$.

$f_x = \lambda g_x$.

$f_y = \lambda g_y$.

$f_z = \lambda g_z$.

Solving this equation, we have $(x, y, z) = (\frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s)$.

$(\frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s, \frac{2}{3} s)$ is the only candidate for local maximum or local minimum.

What should I do next?

If $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is a maximum point on $S$,

then

$f_x(x_0, y_0, z_0) = \lambda g_x(x_0, y_0, z_0)$

$f_y(x_0, y_0, z_0) = \lambda g_y(x_0, y_0, z_0)$

$f_z(x_0, y_0, z_0) = \lambda g_z(x_0, y_0, z_0)$

for some $\lambda$.

Is this true?

Comment: `What should I do next?` Can $f$ have a *minimum* on $S\,$? If not, then what you found must be a maximum.

Comment: It's in fact simpler without Lagrange: you have $3$ positive numbers $a=s-x, b=s-y, c=s-z$ which sum to $s$ and are looking for the maximum product $a\cdot b\cdot c$. By AM-GM that's when $a=b=c$.